# Is there any value to having quality on a lamp?

Tags: rimworld

[image]

It doesn't seem to make a difference what quality a lamp is. Is there a hidden bonus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A high quality lamp will have a higher market value.

Market value is one of the factors contributing to room quality, so it could help appease Jealous or Greedy colonists. It's a relatively small increase compared to adding art, but every little helps.

Comment: thats the answer @KitSunde